# Relationship between kinetic friction and angle of friction

Tags: friction

For a body moving on a horizontal surface, is the angle of friction equal to the coefficient of kinetic friction?

Answer (score 0):

Angle of friction is not equal to coefficient of kinetic friction.It is equal to coefficient of limiting friction and coefficient of limiting friction is always greater than coefficient of kinetic friction.

Answer (score 0):

The angle of friction is related to the coefficient of static friction, not kinetic friction. Wikipedia defines it as "the maximum angle at which a load can rest motionless on an inclined plane due to friction without sliding down". Clearly the reference to "motionless" means the friction force is static, not kinetic. Also, while the angle of friction is a function of the coefficient of friction, they are not equal. The former has units of degrees or radians while the latter is  unitless.

A similar concept applies to the example of a block resting on a horizontal surface with an applied force at an angle with the horizontal. In this case it's the minimum angle between the applied force and the horizontal before the horizontal component of the force exceeds the maximum possible static friction force, and motion is impeding

Hope this helps.